# how can i fix those failed?

Tags: software-installation

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.1)/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.1)/dists/quantal/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.1)/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.1)/dists/quantal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.1)/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.1)/dists/quantal/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.1)/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.1)/dists/quantal/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Hint... it says `cd-rom` ...

Answer (score 0):

Edit your sources.list with `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Delete the line with the Install CD (probably the first or second line, starts with "deb cdrom: ") and the line with the PPA-URL in it. If this line is not there take a look at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and delete the files with the PPA of gwibber.

Comment: Process no longer exists: 5560.  Creating new pid lock file.